Best way to make font sizes responsive in Mantine UI
In mantine UI <Text> component you can set the size of the text by using the size prop, which takes a size from the mantine theme and is a value like sm or xxl.
My question is this ... for smaller screen sizes sm and xxl should be different than for very big screen sizes.
What's the easiest way to configure the font-sizes in Mantine for different screen sizes.
The best idea I have so far is to redefine the the rem size on the :root element.
Is there a better way ?

The idea of redefining the root font size and relying on the "rebasing" of the derivative REM-based font sizes is a good one and is reflective of the whole point in REM in the first place. There are ways to change specific elements to have a different font size dependant on screens (breakpoints) -- but you have to think if that's what you really want before doing it as it opens up a whole new area you need to think about on an ongoing basis. It's a trap to start thinking in that way, unless understanding the implications.  The REM approach is legitimate. Go with it, until you find an issue.
